# Bash script to count characters in a newspaper text file and create CSV output

Tags: bash, file, txt

I have a text file that is around 80K lines and 5.6 MB, composed of several newspaper articles. There are approximately 900 articles of various sizes. The file is encoded in UTF-8, language is French (accents).

I would like to count the number of characters of each article and store the result in a CSV file formatted like:

```
article1;numchar1
article2;numchar2
...
```

By character, I mean letters, numbers, punctuation and spaces. I don't want to count the `\n` (file has been generated on a Linux machine).

A new article starts with a line with the name of the newspaper (say news01, news02, ...). I can list them (around 15 differences). I would like that lines + 1 or 2 lines after (fixed number for each newspaper) to be ignored.

There are also disclaimer lines I don't want to be included in the counting. Disclaimer length is 2 or 3 lines, always the same for the same newspaper).

I was thinking of building sort of an array that contains the name of the newspaper, the number of header lines and the number of disclaimer lines. Like this:

```
declare -A INFOS
INFOS[news01N]="Newspaper 1 name"
INFOS[news01H]=1
INFOS[news01D]=2
INFOS[news02N]="Newspaper 2 name"
INFOS[news02H]=2
INFOS[news02D]=1
```

where newsXX is the id of the newspaper, newsXXN for name, H for header and D for disclaimer. These lengths are fixed for each newspaper so that should be okay.

The remaining text (that is, between the name of the newspaper and the next disclaimer) is considered to be the article. That should be accurate enough for my study.

Here is a sample file:

```
news01
this line to be ignored too

this is the 
first article 
of the file

disclaimer to 
be ignored


news02
these lines to be
ignored too

this is the 
        second article 
    of the file

disclaimer to be ignored
```

that should output:

```
news01;37
news02;38
```

Some lines may start or end with random number of spaces or tabulations. I would like them to be reduced to max one space character (see above).

May I ask for your help realising a bash script to do that counting?

I am really new to bash scripting and here is what I have so far :

```bash
#! /bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" != *"news01"* ]]; then
        echo ${#line};
    fi
done < $1
```

This is inspired from posts I have seen here. It is still very far from my goal but this is all I've got as a MWE.

Comment: Good show including your attempt to code a solution and your required output. Please update your Q with a small bit of sample data. Note you don't have to dump the whole file to your posting. Hopefully you can find about 10 lines, that if processed would contain the information you need to extract. If I'm understand your need, I think `awk '{print $1 ":" length($0)}' file` might be a better place to start. Good luck.

Comment: how do you know the number of lines to ignore (after `newsXX`, as part of `disclaimer`) for each `newsXX`? are these numbers in a file? please update the question with sample counts for `news01` and `news02`

Comment: please update the question with the definition of 'character' ... do you count spaces and tabs? do you count punctuation? do you count the end-of-line character (eg, `\n`, or `\r\n` if windows line endings)?

Comment: Before writing any code, you have to figure out an algorithm - specific criteria - you will use to decide which lines to include, or not.  In your sample data, news01 must ignore the next line, news02 must ignore two lines.  How will your code know?  Same for disclaimer.  You could `grep -iv disclaimer` but that would not filter multi-line disclaimers.  There has to be a programmable - specific way to know what to keep and what to remove.  It might make sense to a human, but not code.  Once you have that, turning it into code is easy.

Comment: I don't see the point for the `INFOS` array. You don't seem to use it in your code. I also don't understand, whether your problem is to come up with an algorithm for this task (i.e. you have never in your life written a computer program before), or whether you could do this in some other language you are familar with, but just don't know how to express it in bash.

Comment: Also, specify the encoding of your text. Some tools in the Linux realm just assume that one character equals one byte, and if you have a mult-byte encoding, this restricts the toolset you can use. Honestly, I wouldn't use bash for this type of task.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you for your answers. I did specify the encoding, it's UTF-8. Language is french, there are letters like éàùçêïÿ.

Comment: @user1934428 I could do it in PHP but I am interested in learning bash a bit. I couldn't find anything like associative arrays in bash. And yes, I am not using the INFOS array in my code because I am kind of lost in bash scripting ^_^' This syntax is so new to me.

Comment: @shellter Impressive simplicity of the instruction, thank you. I will look at `awk` documentation to find a way to access the read content and if there is a way to sum the values between lines.

Comment: @markp-fuso I replied by editing my post. Please look at the INFOS array. Numbers are newspaper specific. I also replied on the characters I want to count.

Comment: bash [does have](https://linuxhint.com/associative_array_bash/) associative arrays, but I find them awkward to use. Basically, bash is not made for text processing. Also, arrays in bash are not first-class citizens. It is inconvient to pass them to bash functions, so most people end up using the arrays as global variables. For learning a language, choose a task for which the language was originally intended. Also, do you need an associative array here? Once you calculate the word count for an article, you can write the result (newspaper/article/count) to your output file. No need to keep it.

Comment: How are things going? If you have tried some new code, update your question with what you think is your best attempt. (I'm out for the afternoon, will check again later). Will try to give you an `awk` sketch later.) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to do complex (read: anything but trivial) text processing, `sed` and `awk` are your best friends.

Here's an `awk` script that fits your example. It ignores all blank lines, so it assumes that, when you specify the number of lines to skip, headers start with a non-blank line and disclaimers end with a non-blank line.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# Run with:
#  ./newscount.awk DATA_FILE
# Debug output:
#  awk -v debug=1 -f newscount.awk DATA_FILE
BEGIN {
  # Initialization.
  name[1] = "news01"
  hdrs[name[1]] = 1  # Header lines to skip.
  disc[name[1]] = 2  # Disclaimer lines to skip.
  chrs[name[1]] = 0  # Chars in articles from this newspaper.

  name[2] = "news02"
  hdrs[name[2]] = 2
  disc[name[2]] = 1
  chrs[name[2]] = 0

  paper = "" # Current newspaper name.
}

# Ignore lines that are blank or contain only spaces.
# I.e. zero or more (`*`) spaces from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`).
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { next }

# Start of a new article: the entire line (`$0`) is one of
# the keys in the `hdrs[]` array. (We could have used any of
# the arrays; the choice is arbitrary.)
$0 in hdrs {
  update_chars(paper)
  paper = $0     # Current newspaper name.
  line = 0       # Line number in current article.
  delete counts  # Array: `counts[line]` contains # of chars in line `line`.
  if (debug) { 
    printf  "Article for %s\n", paper
  }
  next
}

# Save the character count for this line.
paper != "" {
  # Number of chars in this line, with whitespace compressed.
  # Replace one or more (`+`) spaces with a single space (`" "`)
  # everywhere they occur (`"g"`) in the line.
  text = gensub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ", "g")
  # Remove leading and trailing whitespace. Replace zero or more
  # spaces, followed by any chars, followed by zero or more spaces
  # with the "any chars" (`"\\1"`) that we found.
  text = gensub(/^ *(.+) */, "\\1", "g")
  counts[line] = length(text)

  if (debug) { 
    printf "%s %d: %d <%s>\n", paper, line, counts[line], text
  }
  line++
}

END {
  # When we reach the end of the file, add the chars from the last article.
  update_chars(paper)
  for (paper in chrs) {
    printf "%s;%d\n", paper, chrs[paper]
  }
}

# Add the number of chars in this article, ignoring headers and disclaimers.
function update_chars(paper) {
  if (paper == "") {
    return
  }
  h = hdrs[paper]
  d = disc[paper]
  if (line < h + d) {
    printf "Error for %s: cannot skip %d headers and %d disclaimers "\
        "in article with %d lines.\n", paper, h, d, line
    return
  }

  # Sum the chars from the first line after the headers
  # through the last line before the disclaimers.
  for (i = h; i < line - d; i++) {
    chrs[paper] += counts[i]
  }
}
```

---

Output from your example file:

```
$ awk -v debug=1 -f ./newscount.awk news.txt

Article for news01
news01 0: 27 <this line to be ignored too>
news01 1: 12 <this is the >
news01 2: 14 <first article >
news01 3: 11 <of the file>
news01 4: 14 <disclaimer to >
news01 5: 10 <be ignored>
Article for news02
news02 0: 17 <these lines to be>
news02 1: 11 <ignored too>
news02 2: 12 <this is the >
news02 3: 15 <second article >
news02 4: 11 <of the file>
news02 5: 24 <disclaimer to be ignored>
news01;37
news02;38
```

```
$ ./newscount.awk news.txt 

news01;37
news02;38
```